# md-icon not clickable with transform property in a md-list-item

Tags: list, click, icons

I've a md-list with a few md-list-item like this [codepen](http://codepen.io/patapron/pen/RoOmbQ).

Two icon in the md-list have this CSS.

```
.icon-transform{
      transform: rotate(-90deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
}
```

When I try to click over the icon, if it have transform porperty, icon becomes not clickable.

I need the behavior to be like the last md-list-item.

Thnaks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add pointer events to the icon transform prevents all click events from happening on the element.

```
.icon-transform{
     transform: rotate(-90deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
     pointer-events: none;
}
```